# After upgrading D9 to D10, class does not exist error

Tags: upgrading

Having followed the instructions here https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10
I'm seeing

Warning: class_implements(): Class Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBundleAccessCheck does not exist and could not be loaded in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterAccessChecksPass->process()

on any new page load.

Also, although the composer commands apparently succeeded, ../web/core/lib/Drupal.php still shows the version as 9.5.11.

This is using php 8.2 and composer version 2.7.1. Per the suggestions in the upgrading doc linked above I explicitly generated my requirements list and tried updating again, but same result.

Comment: If you run `rm -rf web/core; composer install` does that folder get recreated? If not you're probably missing the composer/installers package